# javascript related question

Tags: javascript

In my below code if z==true the record should save and if z==false the record should not save,instead stay on the same page. 
but since I m using this line **if(z==true)** confirm box itself not appering.can anyone help me??

```
if('{!m}' == 'true' || '{!n}' == 'true'){
  var z=confirm(' Are you sure');
  }
if(z==true){
return true;
}
else{
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

z is undefined when you try to use it outside the first if. checking the browser console *could* give you that clue

try:

```
var z;
if('{!m}' == 'true' || '{!n}' == 'true'){
  z=confirm(' Are you sure');
  }
if(z==true){
return true;
}
else{
return false;
}
```

Comment: No this also not working

Comment: Then your problem is with the {!} variables. If they are not true on page load the will not update unless you serenader the script block. And define not working. Because you say in your question that confirm box is not showing because you are using `if(z == true)` yet that is not the condition for the box to appear